# How to remove tool tip percentage in livechart

Tags: c#, livecharts

[image]

I use Stack Column bar in livecharts and when I hover the bar column, Active Tooltip.
But I want to remove percentage.

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
yourChart.ToolTip = null;
yourChart.Hoverable = false;
```

Comment: I Use Toop tip but remove  only percentage

Answer (score 1):

I think you can set the propertie IsWrapped to false. Like in the code :).

```
<lvc:CartesianChart Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}">
<lvc:CartesianChart.DataTooltip>
    <lvc:DefaultTooltip BulletSize="20" Background="Gray" IsWrapped ="false"/>
</lvc:CartesianChart.DataTooltip>
```

https://lvcharts.net/App/documentation/beta/LiveCharts-Wpf-DefaultTooltip

I hope it works.